# Help understanding certain properties of rings

Tags: abstract-algebra

I am studying ring theory. Let $R$ be a set together with two binary operation "$+$", "$.$". Then $R$ is said to be ring if $(R,+)$ is an abelian group and $(R, .)$ is a semi group, and also distributive laws are satisfied.

My question is: what is the meaning of this question

> Let $R$ be a ring with $a, b$ belonging to $R$. Then
>
> 1. $a0=0a=0$
> 2. $a(-b)=(-a)b=-ab$
> 3. $(-a)(-b)=ab$

Comment: ... what do you mean "what is the meaning of 1, 2, and 3"?

Comment: Perhaps your difficulty is that the definition of "ring" that you described uses a dot for the multiplication operation and the formulas 1, 2, and 3 write multiplication simply as $ab$ rather than $a.b$ .  The meaning of the other symbols in 1, 2, and 3 , namely $0$ and the minus signs, should be included in the definition of the "abelian group" part of your definition of "ring".

Answer (score 1):

1. $0$ is the additive identity element. Statement (1)
   $$a0 = 0a = 0$$ tells you that multiplying anything by the additive identity gives the additive identity. Just like our familiar experience in the real numbers. For example, $0\cdot 2 = 0$.
2. $-a$ is the additive inverse of $a$. Statement (2) 
   $$a(-b) = (-a)b = -(ab)$$ tells you that the additive inverse of the product of $a$ and $b$ is the same as the product of either by the additive inverse of the other. Just like our familiar experience in the real numbers. For example $(-2)3 = 2(-3) = -6 = -(2\cdot3)$.
3. Statement (3) $$(-a)(-b) = ab$$ tells you that the product of two numbers is the same as the product of their additive inverses. Just like our familiar experience in the real numbers. For example $(-2)(-3) = 6 = 2\cdot 3$.

To prove (1), you could note that since $a = a + 0$, we have $a(a) = a(a + 0)$, and apply the distributive property.

To prove (2), consider $a(b + (-b))$.

To prove (3), apply $(2)$ twice.